# On Linux, why does python path.abs_path have a space at the start?

Tags: python, linux, split, path

I wanted to get the directories in a path, so I did:

```
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
self.dir = directory
```

I then did this:

```
self.path = os.path.abspath(self.dir)
self.path_list = self.path.split(os.path.sep)
```

If I now print self.path_list, I get:

```
['', 'home', 'marienbad', 'python3']
```

Why is there an empty string at the start?

Comment: Because there's an empty string between the start of the string and the first path separator in `'/home/marienbad/python3'`? That's how split works in general, it's not really specific to paths.

Comment: What? No there isn't.  print("directory=", end="") print(directory) - there is no space between the = and the /. the_string = "this is a string" words = the_string.split() print(words) = ["this", "is", "a", "string"] again, no space.

Comment: A space `' '` is **not** the same thing as an empty string `''`.